# Why React Hooks Must Be Named With "use"?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the [ReactJS docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook), they specify this rule:

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks

I couldn't find any explanation for this naming convention, and why it has to be strictly enforced. Are there actual compile/transpile stages which depend on this naming? Is it an "aesthetic/semantic" guideline enforced with a heavy hand?

Comment: Probably just an opinion. I can see why... a 'Hook' [noun] is a thing. Therefore, you 'use' [verb] that thing.

Comment: The rules-of-hooks eslint plugin can only work if you follow this convention. https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks